# django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "[]": syntax error

Tags: django, django-migrations

There is this error showing after I have used makemigrations command
I have tried commenting different column for it but it wont work

```
    C:\Users\Rushabh\Desktop\project\MyPrj>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, paper, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying paper.0014_auto_20170405_1549...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 335, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "[]": syntax error

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 84, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 231, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 191, in _remake_table
    self.create_model(temp_model)
  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 295, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 112, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 335, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "[]": syntax error
```

**Migration file**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import django.contrib.postgres.fields
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('paper', '0019_auto_20170405_1659'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='test',
            name='checked',
            field=models.BooleanField(default=False),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='test',
            name='mark3',
            field=django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField(base_field=models.CharField(max_length=5), default=[], size=None),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='test',
            name='mark4',
            field=django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField(base_field=models.CharField(max_length=5), default=[], size=None),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='test',
            name='mark7',
            field=django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField(base_field=models.CharField(max_length=5), default=[], size=None),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='test',
            name='request',
            field=models.BooleanField(default=False),
        ),
    ]
```

The problem arose after I added the following field to my models

```
mark3=ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=5),default=[])
```

The models.py file is

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class User(models.Model):
    user_id=models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    role=models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_id


class Qbank(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qbank_id=models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50,blank=False)
    # subject_id=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    qbank_file=models.FileField(upload_to= 'qbs/',blank=False)
    ans_file=models.FileField(upload_to= 'ans/',blank=False)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.qbank_id


class Test(models.Model):
    qbank=models.ForeignKey(Qbank,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    test_id=models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50)
    request=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    checked=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    mark3=ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=5),default=[])
    mark4=ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=5),default=[])
    mark7=ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=5),default=[])
    # true if send and checked respt
    def __str__(self):
        return self.test_id
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I puzzled over this one for a little while too. The ArrayField is specific to Postgres, and is imported from a Postgres library:

```
import django.contrib.postgres.fields
```

It looks like you're trying to commit your migrations to SQLite. You should set up a local Postgres database, and update your `settings.py` file from:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

To:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'DATABASE NAME',
        'USER': 'USER NAME',
        'PASSWORD': 'USER PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Also, you are incorrectly setting the default value for your ArrayField. Per [Django ArrayField documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/), you should not use [] as the default. It won't cause this problem, but it will probably create some others! You should use `default=list` instead of `default=[]`, which will create a mutable default shared between all instances of ArrayField:

Instead of:

```
mark7=ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=5),default=[])
```

Try:

```
mark7=ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=5),default=list)
```

Answer (score 1):

I stupidly used this specific posgresql field - ArrayField for the model and let the test run with sqlite. That caused the error when I pushed code to github with the travis-ci.

Answer (score 1):

The fix is to simply remove the new migration files which has not been applied. You can see those by running the command.

```
python manage.py showmigrations
```

The files against which the 'tick' is absent are the ones that can be safely removed. Once removed, then go to the models.py and remove the `ArrayField` field.

Run the `makemigrations` command again followed by the `migrate` command. This time it should work.

If you want to use the `ArrayField` field then you should use  postgres database in your project.

Answer (score 0):

The [`ArrayField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) docs warn that you shouldn't use a mutable value like `[]`. You can use the callable `list` for an empty default.

```
class Test(models.Model):
    ...
    mark3=ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=5), default=list)
    mark4=ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=5), default=list)
    mark7=ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=5), default=list)
```

After making this change, delete the old migration file and run `makemigrations` again.

Comment: Sorry that sounds like a separate issue, and I can't tell the problem from the info you've given. If this is a test project with new models, the easiest fix is probably to drop the database, delete the migration files, create new migrations and then migrate.