# Adding array field OperationalError

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, operationalerror

I am very new to django(version 1.11).I am trying to make a shoppingwebsite and i am confused in creating Order model.
In here you can see my first (version 1) models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField


class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20 , default='')
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 100 , default='')
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_image',blank=True)
    vojood = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    unique = models.CharField(max_length = 100 ,default='')
    typ = models.CharField(max_length = 100 ,default='')
    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name
    @classmethod
    def turn_on(prds,pk):
        prds[pk].vojood=true

    @classmethod
    def turn_off(prds,pk):
        prds[pk].vojood=false
class Order(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 300 , default='')
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 300 , default='')
    time = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    arrived = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    basket = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=300,default=''),default=list)
    def __str__ (self):
        return self.username
```

After `python manage.py makemigrations` when i tried to migrate the new field (arrayfield) with `python manage.py migrate` i got a very long error . So the last line was `django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "[]": syntax error`So i deleted the new field(arrayfield) and again i used makemigrations but the error during migrate did not change.And now i cant migrate any field with any type!
And here is my Error :

```
E:\django projects\4\third>python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'shop':
  shop\migrations\0013_auto_20180611_1518.py
    - Alter field basket on order

E:\django projects\4\third>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: accounts, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, shop
Running migrations:
  Applying shop.0005_order_prds...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 63, in
execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line
326, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "[]": syntax error

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283,
 in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330,
 in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py
", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 11
5, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_i
nitial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 14
5, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_
initial)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 24
4, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 1
29, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, projec
t_state)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py"
, line 87, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", lin
e 238, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", lin
e 198, in _remake_table
    self.create_model(temp_model)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 3
03, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 1
20, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in
execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in
execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise

    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 63, in
execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line
326, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "[]": syntax error

E:\django projects\4\third>
```

I also changed the name of array field from prds to basket but you can see in the error the name did not change !!!!! And it runs 0005_order_prds despite  the last created migration is 00013_etc !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are using a SQLite database, you need to use a Postgres database - [see this similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43231618/django-db-utils-operationalerror-near-syntax-error?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I will try.but now i have lots of data in my database if i change database what will happen for them?

Comment: you could migrate the contents of your database to the new database - maybe this will help https://gist.github.com/sirodoht/f598d14e9644e2d3909629a41e3522ad